# why does a matched rewriterule not work?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteRule    ^a/(.*)$ api.php?params=$1 [L,QSA]
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I expect that when I go to `/a/test` that the server returns `/api.php?params=test`

Instead, the third rule is matched.

If I comment out the third rule, then the first rule works.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventhough you have the `L` flag, which stops rewriting *for the current rewriting iteration*, the result (the rewritten URI) will be put back into the rewrite engine, and will continue to do so, until the URI going into the rewrite engine comes out unchanged. So what's happening is the first rule gets applied, then `api.php?params=test` is put back into the rewrite engine, where the 3rd rule gets applied.

You can either turn off all looping, by passing through the URI if an internal redirect was made, by adding this *right underneath `RewriteEngine On`*:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Or add a condition to the 3rd rule so that it ignores requests to existing resources:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

Or add an explicit condition to ignore `api.php`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api\.php
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```